# How do I implement Kafka Consumer in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement a kafka consumer in scala. I've seen a million tutorials for how to do it in Java, and even some ([like this one](http://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0.9-consumer-client)) that say it's for scala but it's written in Java.

Does anyone know where I can find an example of how to write it in Scala? I've only just started to learn Scala so maybe the linked example can be used in Scala even though it's written in Java or something, but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing at the moment. Everything I google just links me to how to do it in Java.

Comment: You can use all the Java code in Scala with very very little changes.

Comment: Can I just do the class in Java and then just import it into the class I want to use it in? Or will I need to rewrite all the variables and things to be scala instead?

Comment: Nevermind, my scala test won't recognize the java class. Here's the class in Java (http://pastebin.com/tnS9Amie), I just don't know enough about scala to convert it. Does it look like it would be possible?

Comment: Would you elaborate on "won't recognise"? What's going on? How is your project structured?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason you're seeing most of the examples in Java is that the new `KafkaProducer` starting 0.8.2.2 is written in Java.

Assuming you're using sbt as your build system, and assuming your working with Kafka 0.8.2.2 (you can change the version as needed), you'll need:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.2.2",
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.2",
  )
}
```

A simple example should get you started:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer 

object KafkaExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.put("group.id", "consumer-tutorial")
    properties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])

    val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe("firstTopic", "secondTopic")

    while (true) {
      val results = kafkaConsumer.poll(2000).asScala
      for ((topic, data) <- results) {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the consumer should talk to the zookeeper clients rather than the brokers?

Comment: @AvihooMamka Kafka no longer "requires" ZooKeeper to track offsets. It's entirely up to you how you do that. And in general, a consumer talks to the brokers for consumption.

Comment: `results` are always `null`. What do I missed?

Comment: @ItayB Are you sure you're consuming from the right topic? Does it have messages? What is your consuming strategy? earliest or latest?

Comment: Yes, I'm consuming from the right topic. I run console consumer which consume messages. I tried both strategies and both offsets. My suspicious is 'bootstrap.servers' which is not necessary in 0.8.2.2 (from the docs) but is mandatory in this specific client..

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov something strange. I tried to debug this thing. I'm using kafka 0.8.2.2 and the same libraries as you mentioned above. The `poll` doesn't have have implementation, it's only a stub that returns `null` - and that's why it doesn't work. In 0.9.0.0 it does have implementation but my version is 0.8.2.2. I'll have to find different API to consume messages

Comment: @ItayB You need [this](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java), see the implementation there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks! please look at line 553 in your link. It's an empty stub. that's why I get `null` all the time. Most of the implementations there use `poll`. Can you please refer me to the relevant lines? waiting for your update :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also look to a working template totally build on Scala here:  https://github.com/knoldus/activator-kafka-scala-producer-consumer 
This application contains the code that you want to use in here.

I hope I solved your problem thanks !